# Welcome page in REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am implementing a Restful Web Service using Jersey. I want to show index.jsp as welcome page.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Rest Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Rest is working!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine when I use this code in my web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/whatever/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

The problem is when the user-pattern is like this:

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Everything works fine except welcome page. I appreciate Any help.

Comment: What is this running on? Websphere, Tomcat, JBoss?

Comment: why are you using /* as your url-pattern instead of something like /rest/*? You might run in to name conflicts.

Comment: yes, I can do that, but still I would know how can I fix this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an alternative way to do this. instead of using index.jsp, I can use a class like:

```
@Path("/")
public class Hello {

    // This method is called if HTML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
       return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Rest Page" + "</title>"
          + "<body><h1>" + "REST is Working!" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
}
```

In web.xml I do not need to use:

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

And it works fine with:

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: For the record, I do not recommend this method at all for a REST API. Your backend code should not be dictating how your data is displayed in the front-end.

Comment: @smcg I agree about the content served, but I think the method is great.

Answer (score 3):

Well servlet mapping calls your servlet. If you want to create a homepage then you should not give /* to the servlet because it will overlap.

When your url pattern is `/whatever`your servlet will run under `localhost:8080/myApp/whatever` and and homepage will have `Localhost:8080/myApp`. However whn you define your url pattern as `/*` both your servlet and home page have tha same place. So remove your servlet mapping or give it a different place other than `/*`

Comment: Yes, it was a good point, thanks. I also found an alternative way.