# Jersey: Implementing a welcome page

Tags: http, jersey, web.xml

I want to create a welcome page whenever the context root of my Jersey application is accessed. Unfortunately the servlet mapping is set as `/*`on my web.xml and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396160/welcome-page-in-rest-with-java-jax-rs-using-jersey) link, it's bad to have the servlet and the homepage at the same place. At the moment, if I change the URL pattern of my servlet, it will require lots of code changes which we want to prevent so we're going for the bad practice by just generating the welcome html page using the back end code.

Seeing that this is already the dirty way, how can we make it a little bit cleaner? Is there a better way to import jsp and css files? I don't want to hard code them all into a single String. :(

Comment: hi, does my answer solve you problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a filter to intercept the request, in the filter, check whether the request url is '/', if so, forward the request to the welcome page.

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        servletContext = config.getServletContext();
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String path = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getPathInfo();
        if(path.equals("/")){
            servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/welcome.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request,response);
        }
    }
}
```

apply the filter in web.xml:

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>welcomeFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>the filter class</filter-class>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>welcomeFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
```