# Jersey Welcome page not working

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm having some trouble getting my welcome(index.html) page to display using Jersey. No matter what I try I get a 404.

my App.java

```
System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
    config.packages("co.java.jersey");

    ServletHolder servlet = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(config));

    Server server = new Server(2222);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server,"/rest/*");
    context.addServlet(servlet,"/rest/*");

    try{
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    finally {
        server.destroy();
    }
```

My web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <display-name>Jersey</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>co.twoic.licensing.App</param-value>
        <!--<param-value>co.twoic.licensing.EmbeddedServer</param-value>-->
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I have tried following this: [Welcome page in REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396160/welcome-page-in-rest-with-java-jax-rs-using-jersey)

My index.html contains more than just basic html so I definitely want my index page used rather than just writing out html.

But when I try localhost:2222 or localhost:2222/index.html
I only get a 403 error

Note:very new to java/jetty/jersey
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the code snippet is rather incomplete here a guess: `localhost:2222/rest/index.html`

Comment: what more can I provide? Also localhost:2222/rest/index.html still gives me a 404

Comment: This question you have answered yourself. Because the fix was related to something which is not part of your qustion. That's why a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is most oft the time appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Removed welcome file from web.xml and added it in code

```
ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
        resourceHandler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html" });
        resourceHandler.setResourceBase("src/Web");
```

setResourceBase was the key to making it work